# Place node label BELOW external nodes in tree with forest

Tags: positioning, labels, alignment, forest

I'm new to LaTeX and need to make a beamer presentation in which I want to show a tree like the one below. As I have limited time I used forest for this because it seemed the easiest and fastest way for me to do this.

Now I want numbers to be below the external nodes. Optimal solution would be small numbers below and outside the node itself but for now I would be glad for small numbers inside the node and smaller distance between real node entry and selfmade "label" in new line.

I've tried `label` as well as `pin` option in node but it's not below like I wanted it. Can anyone please help me? This is like I try to make it look like: [image: tree with label below nodes]

This is what I already achieved:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
                for tree={circle, draw, 
                 minimum size=1.5em,
                    inner sep=1pt, 
                   align=center, top color=white},
                for leaves={rectangle}     
            [, top color=gray, bottom color=gray, minimum size=4mm
             [E
               [ILIG, pin={\tiny 3}]
               [U
                 [CH,label=1]
                 [LE\\ \scriptsize 5]]]
             [FLOG \\ \scriptsize 2]
             [GEL
                 [BE\\ \scriptsize 7]
                 [D\\ \scriptsize 8]]
             [MIT\\ \scriptsize 4]
             [ZU\\ \scriptsize 6]]
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: What it looks like]

After using the suggested solution I recieved the following error in `frame` environment: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe.1 \end{frame}
Fixed error by adding `[fragile]` after frame, so this is working code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw, 
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=1pt, 
    align=center, top color=white
  },
  for leaves={rectangle},
  my label/.style={label={[font=\scriptsize]south:#1}},
  [, top color=gray, bottom color=gray, minimum size=4mm
    [E
      [ILIG, my label=3]
      [U
        [CH, my label=1]
        [LE, my label=5]]]
    [FLOG, my label=2]
    [GEL
      [BE, my label=7]
      [D, my label=8]]
    [MIT, my label=4]
    [ZU, my label=6]]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` is the right way to go, but to achieve the desired result, labels need to be placed to the south of the main nodes: `label={south:label text}`.  And the best way to change the font size in the label is using label options: `label={[font=\scriptsize]south:label text}`. More information on key `label` can be found in the PGF/TikZ manual, section 17.10.

Below, `my label` style, setting the placement and font size of a label, is defined for convenient usage in the tree.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw, 
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=1pt, 
    align=center, top color=white
  },
  for leaves={rectangle},
  my label/.style={label={[font=\scriptsize]south:#1}},
  [, top color=gray, bottom color=gray, minimum size=4mm
    [E
      [ILIG, my label=3]
      [U
        [CH, my label=1]
        [LE, my label=5]]]
    [FLOG, my label=2]
    [GEL
      [BE, my label=7]
      [D, my label=8]]
    [MIT, my label=4]
    [ZU, my label=6]]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! This works fine as long as I just use it inside \begin{document} ... \end{document}. If I just put it inside \begin{frame} it no longer works and doesn't compile with this error message: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.<to be read again>1 \end{frame}

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe this is due to how Beamer collects the `frame` environment. Doubling the hashes should do the trick: `my label/.style={label={[font=\scriptsize]south:##1}},`

Comment: Unfortunately the following error stitll occurs: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe.<to be read again>1 \end{frame}. I've added the code I used in my question

Comment: @Michelle Try using `\begin{frame}[fragile]` instead.  This should work.